# Ngrx effect returns returns object instead of array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, effects

I'm trying to get data from api using ngrx effects, the code works correctly, however, when I want to get the animals array for some reason returns { animals:array, loading:true }. Even I specified that I only want the animals atribute simply assings the whole object.

[image: array of animals and loading]

This is the result by console.log but I printed the animals array.

Animal.model.ts

```
export interface Animal {
name: string;
latin_name: string;
animal_type: string;
active_time: string;
length_min: string;
length_max: string;
weight_min: string;
weight_max: string;
lifespan: string;
habitat: string;
diet: string;
geo_range: string;
image_link: string;
id: number;
```

}

animal.actions.ts

```
export const LOAD_ANIMALS:string = "[Animal List] Load animals";
export const LOADED_ANIMALS:string = "[Animal List] Loaded success";

export const loadAnimals = createAction(
    LOAD_ANIMALS
);

export const loadedAnimals = createAction(
    LOADED_ANIMALS,
    props<{ animals: Animal[] }>()
)
```

animal.reducer.ts

```
export const animalInitialState: {
    loading:boolean,
    animals: Animal[];
} = { loading: false, animals: []}

export const animalsReducer = createReducer(
    animalInitialState,
    on(loadAnimals, (state) => {
        return { ...state, loading:true }
    }),
    on(loadedAnimals, (state, result) => {
        return { animals: result.animals, loading: false}
    })
)
```

animal.selector.ts

```
export const selectAnimalsFeature = (state: AppState) => state.animals;

export const selectListAnimals = createSelector(
    selectAnimalsFeature,
    (state: AnimalsState) => state.animals
); 

export const selectLoading = createSelector(
    selectAnimalsFeature,
    (state:AnimalsState) => state.loading
);
```

app.state.ts

```
export interface AppState{
    animals: AnimalsState
}

export const ROOT_REDUCERS: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
    animals: animalsReducer
}
```

animal.effects.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AnimalsEffects {
    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private animalService: AnimalService
    ){}

    loadAnimals$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(LOAD_ANIMALS),
        mergeMap((action) => this.animalService.getAnimals()
            .pipe(
                map((response:Animal[]) => {
             return loadedAnimals({ animals: response});
            }),
            catchError(() => EMPTY)
        ))
))
```

}

animal.component.ts

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  data:Animal[] =[];
  constructor(
    private store: Store<{ animals: Animal[]}>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(loadAnimals());
    this.store.select(selectListAnimals => selectListAnimals.animals).subscribe( 
      (data:Animal[]) => { 
        console.log("ANIMALS " , data.animals); 
        this.data = data.animals; 
        console.log("Data ", this.data)}); // for some reason this.data stores the array and the loading value depite of being type Animal[]
  }

}
```

I don't know why this.data also stores the loading atribute, if its type is Animal[].
The unique error I get is that ngFor cannot loop this.data because is a object type.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you pass wrong selector to store.select(), try below

```
this.store.select(selectListAnimals).subscribe( 
      (data) => { 
        console.log("ANIMALS " , data); 
        this.data = data; 
        console.log("Data ", this.data)});
```